# Scheme infinite recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I'm writing my own version of quicksort, and something is causing an infinite recursion that I can't track down for some reason.

```
(define (quicksort-test list)
  (cond
    ((null? list) '())
    (else
     (appending (quicksort-test (less-than-builder list (car list)))
                (quicksort-test (geq-builder list (car list)))))))
```

Appending is a helper function which just appends one list onto another, and less-than-builder and geq-builder are helper functions which take a list and a pivot as inputs, and then build a list of everything less than the pivot and a list of everything greater than or equal to the pivot, respectively. I think the problem is in my else statement, though I can't see why for some reason, maybe due to a fried brain.

Comment: Actually typing out my question just now, I think I might have seen the issue. I think the problem is my last line. Building a list of every element that's greater than or equal to a pivot element won't ever return an empty list, will it? It will just get down to a single element and keep calling itself over and over again because a list with a single element is always greater than or equal to itself... Is that right?

Comment: Right. You need to remove the pivot element – recurse on `(cdr list)` – and put it back in the middle afterwards. Also, don't use the name `list` for variables as it hides the `list` procedure.

Comment: Oh good call. It doesn't seem to hurt anything in this case specifically to name it list, but I guess it's still bad practice. And recursing on (cdr list) makes a lot more sense than what I did... I can't believe I didn't think of that. I ended up amending my helper function to only output elements greater than the pivot, and added in another helper function to retrieve all the elements equal to the pivot, adding them in in another builder step. It seemed to work just fine but it's a lot less elegant than what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Building a list of every element that's greater than or equal to a pivot element will never return an empty list, it will just get down to a single element and keep calling itself over and over again because a list with a single element is always greater than or equal to itself.

You need to remove the pivot element – recurse on `(cdr list)` – and put it back in the middle afterwards.

Credit goes to molbdnilo and Eddie V for solving this problem in the comments